# How to call controller function from other controller angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services

please look at this code. My button must call function checkResults() from controller CtrlTwo.
How to do this?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function CtrlOne($scope){
    $scope.greet = 'Hi!  ';
}

function CtrlTwo($scope){
    $scope.$emit('checkResults', function(){
        alert('Function is called!');
    }
                );
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="CtrlOne">
        {{greet}}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Check results" ng-href='#here' ng-click='checkResults()'/>
    </div>
    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, hopefully this example will help you:

Javascript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CtrlOne', function($scope){
    $scope.greet = "hi!"
    var nTimes = 0;
    $scope.$on('myEvent', function(){
        $scope.greet = "Hi! The event has been called " + (++nTimes) + " times";
    });
});

myApp.controller('CtrlTwo', function($scope){
    $scope.emitCustomEvent = function(){ $scope.$emit('myEvent'); };
});
```

View:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="CtrlOne">
        {{greet}}
        <div ng-controller="CtrlTwo">
            <input type="button" value="Check results" ng-click="emitCustomEvent()" >
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0nhs48a1/1/)

Comment: Thanks Josep. This answer helps to me.